# What items can be farmed fully automatically?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Cacti have always been farmable [completely automatically](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYYy99_W754). With pistons in 1.7, sugar cane can now be farmed in a [fully automatic fashion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HFJZ4bgVFU) as well. Mobs and animals can be farmed as well in giant [mob grinders](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKZteeNnfVE). To my knowledge these are the only items that can be farmed in a fully automatic fashion in vanilla Minecraft.

Cobblestone can be farmed fully automatically [using mods](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1szZCEq5F4I), or in a semi-automatic fashion [using TNT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXMob52sBCo). Wheat can be farmed [semi-automatically on a massive scale](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNXGKeP4OkY), but unfortunately requires replanting and tilling.

What I'd like to know is if there are any contraptions people have contrived to harvest any other item in a fully automatic way without using any mods.

Comment: I'm debating whether or not this question is appropriate. It seems to be inviting a "list of X," which we tend to close here because they have no real "right" answer. As stated, it seems to just ask for people to list various devices they've created.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes - I agree that the title somewhat gives that impression, and I thought of this too and struggled with its wording, but I tried to present it more as a "am I missing anything?" question than a list question..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Aside from the things you mentioned:

---

### Fully Automatic (no need for player's presence):

*As long as you keep the chunk loaded, you can go on an adventure while your farm is producing*

- Anything that uses a smelter (cooked food, experience generators, etc.)
- **Honey Bottles**, **Honeycomb**

---

### Fully Automatic, as long as player is within 128 blocks of farm

- **Melons & Pumpkins** can be farmed using BUDs.
- **Mushrooms** are [easily farmed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLq4cU7WwRY), since they spread by themselves.
- **Eggs** [can be farmed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qN9TsJWiIT8)
- **Wheat** can be fully automatic using a [farmer villager](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fnatRPiDl4)
- **Bread** with farmer villagers
- **Cactus**
- **Coal**
- **Iron ingots**
- **Gold nuggets**
- **Steak, Raw Beef, Leather** (if you are lucky enough to find a mushroom island)
- **Cobblestone** with Wither or Ghast
- **Cooked Chicken, Raw Chicken, Feathers**
- **Redstone, Gunpowder, Glowstone Dust, Sugar, Wooden Sticks** with a witch farm
- **Slime Balls**
- **Sand & Gravel Duplicators and Flint** (actually a bug, but still possible)
- **Carrots and Raw Potatoes** with farmer villagers
- **String, Spider Eyes**
- **Bones, arrows, bows**
- **Rotten flesh**
- **Seeds and any kind of 1 block flower**
- **Ender pearls**
- **Any kind of potion**
- **Prismarine Shard**
- **Magma cream**
- **Ghast tears**
- **Kelp**
- **Bamboo**
- **Sugar Cane**
- **Wool** (dispenser equipped with shears)
- **Records**

---

### AFK farms:

*You may need to jam the click button, and you wont be able to play while harvesting*

- **Snow** (at some time pre 1.15, this was fully automatic.  No longer.)
- **Any experience farm**
- **Wooden logs** (any type)
- **Tree saplings** (any type)
- **Fish, Name tags, Nautilus shells, saddles, enchatment books**
- **Blaze Rods**
- **Any kind of 2 block tall flower**
- **Animal breeding farm**
- **Dragons Breath**
- **Cocoa beans**
- **Nether Wart**
- **Ice** with a BUD to detect the freezing water (not sure if withers can destroy ice)
- **Stone** (needs silktouch pickaxe)
- **Any Type of Wooden Planks** just craft the output of the log farm
- **Glass and Panes** (smelt and craft the output of the sand duplicator)
- **Flint and Steel** (craft the outputs  of the Iron farm and the gravel duplicator)
- **Mushroom Blocks**
- **Grass and Mycelium** (although it is not technically infinite, it is practically infinite)
- **Emeralds** trading the output of another farm if you get a [perfect villager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYyuASdoc4A)
- **Full diamond toolkit and armor** trading emeralds with a blacksmith villager
- **Mob heads** except wither skeleton (with a [charged creeper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCjaGQNo9-4) farm)

Comment: You can't farm pumpkins.  There is no renewable supply of pumpkin seeds.  You can't craft pumpkins into seeds like you can with melons.

Comment: @John, but the steams will produce pumpkins as long as they're alive. You can farm the pumpkins they produce, but not the pumpkin seeds.

Comment: Ah ok.  I haven't been able to try that because of the bug making pumpkin seeds not spawn in 1.8.  Btw, this answer is an excellent resource!  +1

Comment: Grilled pork machine! Love it!

Comment: Don't think you can farm eggs _quite_ like that any more, too many chickens in a small area and they supposedly start to die, so you end up making raw chicken and feathers instead of eggs. Seen at http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Egg#Trivia

Comment: Melons and pumpkins no longer require tilled soil for the grown block (the stem still requires it). This means they can be fully automated.

Comment: @agf: "If too many chickens are in a small area they will start clipping into walls, and suffocating and dying. This can be alleviated by using glass walls for a chicken coop, since transparent blocks do not cause suffocation." So you just need to use glass block for your farming contraption.

Comment: @Lysarion It was true when I said it, over a year ago. Passive mobs also don't despawn now, so that's not the only thing that's changed.

Comment: oopsie, forgot to check dates....

Comment: Snow is not 100% auto anymore

Comment: ghast tears and spider eyes require player interaction to drop

Answer (score 8):

The lists above are excellent!

But, this question was asked before Minecraft 1.8 so a few things have changed.

Now you can use Villager Farmers to automatically harvest and replant **Carrots**, and **Potatoes**, and **Wheat**.  You can also automatically collect the **Bread** that Villager Farmers make with the wheat.

Another source of automated carrots and potatoes are from zombie mob grinders.

You can fully automate **Pumpkins** and **Sugar Cane**, but not melons.  Any automation will break them into **Melon Slices**.  So Melon Slices can be fully automated.

**Villagers** can also be farmed.  Because you can have them automatically shipped away from the village and stored somewhere else so that more can breed.  I manually do this right now but am building an automated system.

I've built a minecraft world that fully automates most almost everything I can think of.  I made a video tour of this world that you see at:

Answer (score 7):

After a little more than a hour looking up things and figuring out stuff, I think I have a list of all items you can make farms for. (Only the automatic farms). Here is the list and hope this helps.

**Planted Crops**

- Cacti - Cacti farm.
- Sugar Cane - Sugar Cane farm.
- Mushrooms - Mushroom farm.

**Mob Grinders**

- Iron - Iron golem farm.
- Roses - Iron Golem farm.
- Eggs - Chicken farm.
- Bones - Skeleton farm.
- String - Spider farm.
- Rotten Flesh - Zombie farm.
- Blaze Rod - Blaze farm.
- Ghast Tears - Ghast farm.
- Sticks - Witch farm.
- Glass Bottles - Witch farm.
- Glowstone Dust - Witch farm.
- Redstone Dust - Witch farm.
- Sugar - Witch farm.
- Assorted Potions - Witch farm.
- Gunpowder - Creeper/Witch farm.
- Ender Pearl - Enderman farm.
- Magma Cream - Magma Cube farm.
- Gold Nugget - Zombie Pigman farm.
- Gold Sword - Zombie Pigman farm.
- Slime Ball - Slime farm.

Comment: I think this would work better (A) as an edit to the accepted answer and (B) properly formatted.

Comment: Also don't forget to remove the mob drops, cacti, sugarcane, and Wheat - those were mentioned in the OP.

Comment: I think it would be best to keep the stuff listed in the question, if only to better provide a comprehensive list of all the automatically farmable items. That said, Pumpkins/melons appear to be missing. As are all the non-egg chicken drops, considering chickens can lay eggs that are automatically collected, 'hatched', and then fed to a grinder.

Comment: I didn't realize there were fully-automatic farms for Magma Cubes, Zombie Pigmen and Slimes. Could you link some designs?

Comment: sadly, roses are no longer part of the game, so you might want to change that point

Answer (score 1):

I've built a 11x11 tower with a hopper floor, which feeds into a trap chest. The trap chest activates pumpkin and sugar cane farms. Chickens on the hopper level drop eggs, above that is a squid farm creating ink sacs, above that is a cactus farm, and above that is a zombie/creeper/skeleton farm that spawns them and pushes them out, they drop all the way past the farms onto the hopper floor and die. It's almost fully automatic, if not for the trap chest mechanism. Eggs, reeds, pumpkin, ink, cactus, potatoes, bones, arrows, rotten flesh and sulphur are constantly filling my chests.

Comment: Consider posting a few screenshots, a picture is worth a thousand words. You can press F2 to take a screenshot if you're on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

New updates

Crops:
 Bamboo: random tick (player within a radius) / 0 tick (loaded chunk)
 kelp: ramdon tick
Events:
 raid: AFK
   Ominous Banner
   Emerald
   Totem of Undying
   Saddle
   crossbow
   iron axe
   (potions, glow stone dust,...) witch again
   hero of the village (villagers throw junk at you)

A sort of cheating way is afk fishing
   enchanting books
   junk

Answer (score 0):

Cobble can be farmed through withers, don't forget that.
Feathers can be farmed through a cooked chicken farm.
Ink Sacs can also be farmed

That's all I can think of at the moment for autos that wasn't already mentioned by previous people.

Answer (score 0):

I have just completed a fully automatic raw chicken and feather farm, it gives me 4 to 5 stacks of raw chicken for trading with the 4 butchers in a nearby village. the big problem is what to do with all the feathers!!!
I based it on a well tried piston killing method, with all the drops collected and moved by hoppers with the addition of a sorter at the end of the row of hoppers, the eggs are lifted straight back up to the top with a droppervator into a row of hoppers which carry them back to the dispenser at the head of the row of hoppers, when the last hopper is full, the comparator next to the last one signals through a home made signal-to -pulse converter to kill all the birds, then after the pistons retract the signal goes to the front of the farm to start the reloading, simultaneously locking the hopper run, once the dispenser is empty, the circuit for the dispenser turns  off and the hopper run is unlocked, and it works, at last after many an experimental hour on development.

Answer (score 0):

snow can be farmed automatically, by using a snow golem with a piston to break the snow layer under it and fill into a hopper, which funnels into a crafting table to be crafted into a snow block, and funneled out using another hopper into a chest storage system.