# How can I automatically mine wood?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What items can be farmed fully automatically?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/what-items-can-be-farmed-fully-automatically)

Is there any way to go from wood blocks to items without manual intervention?

I'd like to mine wood automatically without having to use my hands/tools.

Comment: What do you mean by "crush"? As far as I know this is not a standard name for any action in Minecraft.

Comment: Click the block and hold down until it breaks?

Comment: Updated, @murgatroid99

Comment: @murgatroid99 Not a dupe. Even if the answer is the same, the question is different.

Comment: It looks to me like this question is a subset of that one. "What items can be farmed automatically?" includes "Is wood one of those items?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, the only way to get from a wood block to a wood item without manually breaking it is to **fuse TNT close enough to the wood block**. Unfortunately, TNT will also do the same to any block within a certain radius and there is a ~70% chance that no item will drop from the destroyed block.

Comment: Could someone explain why the answer was downvoted? If I knew, I might be able to improve it...

Comment: When I first downvoted it I had misinterpreted the question and thought your answer is wrong.

Comment: Not true, other explosions and the wither can also break it, and wither drops 100% of the drops.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. You cannot automatically mine solid blocks (apart from sand and gravel) in the vanilla game. While methods exist for [automatically mining stone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntVBN3kHkQo), there are no resources as output.

You can use TNT, but it's infeasible to do so in any kind of automated fashion, and you lose most of your blocks. You can use fire charges to destroy the blocks, but you'll get no wood in return.